# How to assign the groupby results to a series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
Date    Value
2020    0
2020    100
2020    200
2020    300
2021    100
2021    150
2021    0
```

I want to get the average of the grouped `Value` by `Date` where `Value > 0`. When I tried:

```
df['Yearly AVG'] = df[df['Value']>0].groupby('Date')['Value'].mean()
```

I get `NaN` Values, when I print the line above I get what I need but with the `Date` column.

```
Date
2020    200
2021    125
```

How Can I have the following:

```
Date    Value    Yearly AVG
2020    0        200
2020    100      200 
2020    200      200
2020    300      200
2021    100      125
2021    150      125    
2021    0        125
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is trick replace non matched values to missing values and then using [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new columns filled by aggregate values:

```
df['Yearly AVG'] = df['Value'].where(df['Value']>0).groupby(df['Date']).transform('mean')
print (df)
   Date  Value  Yearly AVG
0  2020      0       200.0
1  2020    100       200.0
2  2020    200       200.0
3  2020    300       200.0
4  2021    100       125.0
5  2021    150       125.0
6  2021      0       125.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Value'].where(df['Value']>0))
0      NaN
1    100.0
2    200.0
3    300.0
4    100.0
5    150.0
6      NaN
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['Yearly AVG'] = df['Date'].map(df[df['Value']>0].groupby('Date')['Value'].mean())
```

Comment: So `transform` accepts argument `mean` and transforms the grouped values from `100,200,...` to their means? Thank you sir.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - yes, exactly, it aggregate values and add to new column by groups.